# Calculating wave strength and frequency from $x$ and $y$ rotation of an object floating on the surface of sea water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, rotational-dynamics, water

I am new here and I'm not a physicist but I have a question about how to find wave strength and frequency by using x and y rotation values of an object floating on water. Basically an object which I can get $x$ and $y$ rotation values from electronic sensors floats on water and I need to find wave strength and frequency by using these values according to change in time. I searched how to obtain desired results online and I found some hits about Navier-Stokes equation. But I don't know how to numerically apply this equation and if it is the right equation to use to get the desired values.

Comment: What do you understand by *wave strength?*

Comment: I might be wrong to express it correct but what I intended to refer by wave strength was force applied by wave on the object floating on water.

Comment: Ah. You might want to look for papers on tidal (wave) energy.

Comment: Ok thank you very much I will check it.